# Hide (or fold) columns of text in (g)Vim (horizontally)

Tags: vim, hide, folding, temporary

is there a way to hide columns of a buffer (text file, you know what I mean) while editing  it in Vim? e.g. text visible in the buffer before hiding column 2&3:

```
abbcccccc
accdddddd
```

And after hiding them:

```
acccccc
adddddd
```

(Not to mention I'm working with really huge files (sometimes over 200 gb).)

And yeah, I had found foldcol.vim, but it requires a patch, and I don't have gcc to compile it as a user on a server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Things might have changed,but in the 6.x days Vi loaded the entire file into a buffer on load. So if you're working with files that are that large(!) you might be running into some problems?

Comment: `http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/foldcol.vba.gz`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cannot be done in stock vim; there is a conceal patch that has not been accepted. The most recent version is only for vim7, and not 7.2 (much less 7.2+patches), so it's probably best considered dead.

Comment: you are not really presenting a solution, merely stating the facts

Comment: this isn't a solution, but it is a great answer. saved me at least an hour looking.

Comment: The solution has been implemented, see this response in 2014:
see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147098/vim-hide-first-n-letters-of-all-lines-in-a-file

Answer (score 3):

Is [foldcol.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1161) maybe what you need? No clue if it works on your huge files though. 200 gb! Impressive in a geeky kind of way. =)

Comment: Umm, you edited your question! Maybe you can compile it on another machine?

Answer (score 2):

The best version I have seen so far is following:

https://github.com/paulhybryant/foldcol

this github project is based on 
http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1161

however it has some improvements - it actually shows hidden column as '*'

it needs vim-maktaba plugin, so in order to install this in your vim, then do following:

add to your ~/.vimrc file :

```
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize                                                    
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim                                                                          
call vundle#begin()                                                                                        

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required                                                                       
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'                                                                              

" Install vim-maktaba plugin for plugin developers - used in foldcol                                       
Plugin 'google/vim-maktaba'                                                                                
" Install foldcol - folding columns using <ctrl-v> visual mark, then :VFoldCol                           
Plugin 'paulhybryant/foldcol'                                                                              

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line                                              
call vundle#end()            " required
```

Notice the two plugins added in the vundle.begin -> vundle.end section ; the vim-maktaba and the foldcol

After adding this to your ~/.vimrc file then start vim as administrator or if you are running on ubuntu then write sudo vim

then write :PluginInstall and if needed then write your user and password for your GitHub account - this will give you access to downloading and installing vim plugins from github

example usage in terminal vim started; use `<ctrl-v>` and mark column :
    [image: before fold]
    [image: after fold]
    [image: after fold clear]

it may seem cumbersome, however it is actually just adding two lines to your ~/.vimrc file and running :PluginInstall

enjoy

Comment: The link to the GitHub repo is dead. Maybe use [this](https://github.com/vim-scripts/foldcol.vim) or [this](https://github.com/sihunqu123/foldcol) as alternatives.